# Difficult Flask Nested For Loop / Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm looking to make a game where, eventually, a table of "0s" can change into different numbers. The intricacies of the game aren't necessarily important here, but I'm having difficulty transitioning my Python code into Flask whereby it keeps updating depending on what happens in the Python code (i.e: if a 0 becomes a 4 or whatnot). Here is what I have in Python to set up the table, and it is pretty clear:

```
numbers = []
for c in range(8):
    for r in range(8):
        numbers.append(0)
```

So each number has a specific c and r coordinate. Then, in flask:

```
{% for row in range(8) %}
    <tr>
        {% for column in numbers %}
            <td>{{ row.column }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The issue is that nothing appears, and I'm confused as to how this continuously updates throughout the game. Please, please, any help?

Comment: Alternatively: Should I be storing these values maybe in a SQL database? To keep track of the 0s vs. not 0s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying 'numbers' list in jinja, row.column is incorrect.

For your existing code, to display the list --

```
{% for row in range(8) %}
    <tr>
        {% for column in numbers %}
            <td>{{ column }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If you are attempting to create a 2D matrix with rows and columns, then either you should use numpy or create 'numbers' as list of lists.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Could you help me in deciphering what a "list of lists" would mean? Sorry, I'm a novice... do you mean like storing each row as a list of its own which is a subset of a larger list?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This way you can reference each row and within that row, each element of that row.

Comment: Accept this answer if it has helped.